# How to refactor global logger that now resides in a static library?

Tags: c++, logging, dll, static-libraries

We have a product comprised of many individual C++ projects - up until recently they were all DLL projects (other than the executables).

Some of these projects never really change and we thought we could reduce some of the overhead devs incur by removing these projects from our day-to-day solutions. They were then changed to build as static libraries and we could provide the devs with the .libs to link against (as well as the PDBs, etc.).

In the process, though, we've broken our logger - which now lives in one of these static libraries. It is declared as a global and we now have many instances being created instead of the single instance as before (when it resided in a DLL project). The main problem with having many instances is that a executable project typically sets the filename - so the filename is only set only for the instance associated with the executable project and not all the other instances of the logger (i.e. logging in other projects is not reflected in the log file).

I understand why this is happening, but am interested to get input into the best way forward from here.

The simplest, I believe, would be to simply revert that particular project back to being a DLL project. However, I'd prefer not to do this as the project contains other things, too.

We could move the logger into a new DLL project - this would be fairly trivial to do, but I can't help but feel there's a 'better' solution (I suppose there always is :P).

In terms of code, before our changes the logger was declared as follows in a cpp:

```
static FileLogger m_fileLogger;
```

The header (that is included in all other projects' PCH) has a macro that uses a global function to interact with *m_fileLogger*.

I'm not sure why it was declared *static*.

I've tried *externing* it in the header, but that didn't change the behaviour (as expected, given the set up with DLL projects statically linking in the logger's project).

Comment: you could probably also build dlls out of those never-changing projects and sitribute those (taking care all devs use the same CRT version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is each dll will load tge static library and therefore the code is dublicates multiple times. Your logger included. Remember that static libraries are just a collection of .obj files.

The only solution is to factor any common code into a common dll and use that throughout but icluding a static lib more than once is extremely wasteful and leads to the problem you decribe with global variables.

When a dll all code and static data is loaded into its own pages. No attempt is made to deduplicate the same coded even it it originated from the same .lib.

When it comes to static (global) data, each dll will hold its own set. The only solution is to have a single copy in a common dll. Otherwise you will have problems.

Comment: As I said - I understand why the problem is happening. Are you saying linking multiple projects to a static lib is wasteful? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I have extended to answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @doron, with this approach I'd move the logger into a new DLL project (there's no need for the other content in this project to be in a dll). I'm going to leave this question open a bit longer  in case anyone else can suggest a different approach.